# React native fetch/axios API calls always goes to catch

Tags: react-native, axios

I have tried using both fetch and axios. But both of these calls fail in my react-native application. It always goes into the catch function. Though calling this API from the browser or from Postman works fine.

```js
axios.get('http://sahajdevapi.letsendorse.com')
.then(function (response) {
  console.warn("res 1: ", response);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.warn("err 1: ", error);
});
```

The error that I get from the catch function is as follows:

```
'err:', { [TypeError: Network request failed]
line: 24115,
column: 31,
sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false'}
```

Comment: your url is not working!

Comment: You can check the url on the browser: http://sahajdevapi.letsendorse.com

Comment: it's website dude

Comment: agree with @HardikVirani , Please check this url in postman and you will get an html response: `<h1 style='text-align: center; color: #ef5a20; margin: 40vh 0;'>SAHAJ</h1>`

Comment: @AnkushRishi Any types of web will respond in postman check any website.
let's say check this one : `https://stackoverflow.com` in postman

Comment: could you check it now? I have changed the response to a JSON object.

Comment: where you test code ? android or ios and OS version ?

Comment: Android, OS - Android Pie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newer version you need to add some security for `http` access.

```
AndroidManifest.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Check your file you need to add in manifest tag `tools` and `uses-library` for that.

Try this one it will work.

Comment: Applied the changes in the manifest, as you mentioned. But it is still not working. It is giving the same error still.

Answer (score 0):

As android VM is an emulator If we use localhost then its points to local host of the android emulator system but not localhost of the development system. So use **system IP** address instead of **localhost**